Scripting a post response in Bruno as an environment variable
I'm trying to grab data from my response in Bruno and set it to the environment variable called bearer_token. Here's the issue. The response is raw and is just the bearer token. So, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do to parse the raw response without a body. I have tried to use just res as the data and setting this as the bearer token, but when I check my response, low and behold, the environment variable is still blank. I have attached my Post Response script (the one given by the Bruno documentation), and it doesn't work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.
function onResponse(res) {
let data = res.getBody();
bru.setEnvVar("bearer_token", data);
}


In the modified snippet, the line let data = res.getBody().toString().trim(); now includes the toString() and trim() methods. The toString() method converts the raw response data into a string format, while the trim() method removes any leading or trailing whitespace from the string. These changes ensure the bearer token is properly processed and cleaned before being stored in the bearer_token environment variable.

Okay, so the new code example would just be:
let data = res.getBody.toString.trim(); and this will set this to the setEnvVar to the proper one. However, when trying this as well it still sets the environment variable when I click environments in Bruno to nothing. It's still blank

function onResponse(res) {
var entire = res.getBody().toString();
var body = entire.slice(entire.indexOf("{") + 1, entire.lastIndexOf("}")).trim();
console.log(body);
bru.setEnvVar("bearer_token", body);
}

That didn't work either.

Your token is generally a key of your data object (and not the "data" itself), in the "Post Response" field, the following script should work :
let data =res.body ;
bru.setEnvVar("token",data.access_token);


This didn't work. "token" is still seen as undefined when looking at the environment variables. What does work is just bru.setEnvVar("token", data) instead of data.access._token since it's just the body. But this did lead to the correct answer. Thank you :)

This is the answer if it's just a response without any other key-value pairs, but just the bearer token as a response.
   let data =res.body ;
    bru.setEnvVar("token",data);

